# jquery.autocomplete doesn't work in compability mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I've read all the results I can find on SO about this without finding anything that applies to me, so don't judge me too quickly :)

I am using `jquery.autocomplete` downloaded from here: http://www.dyve.net/jquery/?autocomplete together with http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js

This all works well in IE8 and FF, but as soon as I activate compability mode in IE8 I keep getting:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

When looking in the call stack, This is the one where it breaks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
$("#123").autocomplete("www.google.se");
}); 


</script>
```

and then the calling function is this:

```
    if ( jQuery.readyList ) {
        // Execute all of them
        jQuery.each( jQuery.readyList, function(){
            this.call( document, jQuery );
        });
        // Reset the list of functions
        jQuery.readyList = null;
    }
```

where this line throws the error:

```
this.call( document, jQuery );
```

Does anybody know why this happens? As mentioned above, works super in IE8 and firefox, but not in compability mode(IE7)

EDIT: changed the autocomplete code to have no dependencies on methods or textboxes

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a minimal code sample where the same problem is occurring, so we can replicate the problem and then look what solves it

Comment: @Jasper The above code should be enough. Given that friendsearch is the id of the textbox and the function called in autocompelte returns a list of possible entries, one per row

Comment: Have you tested with jQuery 1.4.2 to see if the bug might be related to 1.3.2 or not?

Comment: @Oskar Kjelling should be, could be, might be. A minimal code sample is usually a very small application (or website in this case) that shows the problem, which can make it a lot easier to fix and makes sure that we have enough information to fix the problem. So, yeah, it might not be necessary, but I would request it, as it would give us a better point to start from.

Comment: @azatoth I got the same thing there

Comment: @Jasper Have a look at the code now, gives me the exception as well

Comment: I tried putting together a sample to see the error. Could not reproduce, you'll probably have to provide a link to a minimal sample that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @lambacck please see my edit in the main question

Answer (score 1):

Add [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to the page and then use console.log() to find out which object and method the error is referring to.